# Show-Command cmdlet layout

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm currently experimenting with [PowerShell Show-Command cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849915.aspx).

I discovered that parameters are shown in alphabetic order (except mandatory ones which are at the top). Is there a way to keep the `param()` order or position (`[parameter(Position=0)]`) order ?

Also, is there a way to show default values?

Comment: Microsoft blog from [PoSh-3 (2012)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/04/13/running-show-command-for-a-cmdlet.aspx) indeed says : "Additional details:

    In each parameter set tab, parameter names are displayed alphabetically, but mandatory parameters are listed first."